# React Native. What is inner logic of starting guide screen of mobile app?

Tags: react-native, navigation

We start an app and there you see screen with multiple pages guide about how to use this app etc. How it works?
My suggestions: I have guide key in firebase, I load its value in local store on start. Its default value is 1. 1 - should show it, 0 - shouldn't show it. When I start I show it by default, but when user reaches the last screen, I set value of guide key to 0. And the guide is just a list of scenes (react-native-router-flux). Is it correct or not? What are best practices? What library allows me to create connected screens with dot navigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently implemented this. I would completely avoid having a guide key in firebase, because you can accomplish it locally. You can use async storage to write a boolean to storage like `userDidCompleteGuide`. Then, when you startup the app, if that value is not defined when reading from async storage, you know to display the guide component. After completing the guide, save that boolean to async storage. If you already use redux-persist, you can have it persist it through redux too.

I used react-navigation along with [fluid transitions](https://github.com/fram-x/FluidTransitions) with react native for animating shared objects on screen.

On a basic level, it's really easy to create a dot component in react native, so don't use a library for it. It's just a view with a width, height, borderRadius, and color. Change the color to indicate an active or inactive dot depending the screen you're on. You can put a few of them in a row to show sequential steps, having the first one show an active color (like white) and the others be gray. You can then wrap your entire guide screen in a touchable opacity. That way, you can tap anywhere on the screen to advance to the next page of the guide, and when doing so, you can set the second dot to be white and the first to be gray. You could have the dots on both pages, and just change the color and nothing else when changing pages. Or you could have them be the same component and show the actual page above and dynamically change the color based on which page is active using the component state. Just set the state when changing to the next screen using the touchable opacity to indicate which should be active, and then display the page based off of that.